# Apollo Client - Simultaneous subscriptions from same component

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to make 2 simultaneous subscriptions with Apollo Client but the connection get closed and reopened every 2 seconds:

[image]

This is my code concerning subscriptions:

```js
//apollo.js

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  includeUnusedVariables: true,
  uri:
    process.env.API_GRAPHQL ||
    // Change to your graphql endpoint.
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      "Bearer TOKEN",
  },
});
const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: process.env.WS_GRAPHQL,
    connectionParams: {
      Authorization:
        "Bearer  TOKEN",
    },
    options: {
      reconnect: true,
    },
  })
);
const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
    return kind === "OperationDefinition" && operation === "subscription";
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
);
```

```js
// subscriber executer

    const {
      result: locationUpdates,
      // loading: loadingLocation,
      // error: devicesError,
      // refetch: refetchDevices,
      onResult: onResultLocations,
    } = useSubscription(locationsLivesTrue, () => ({
    }));

    const { result: me, onResult: onResultMe } = useSubscription(
      meUpdates,
      () => ({})
    );
```

If I execute only one subscription it works fine.
I also tried to subscribe directly from the client when I provide the app, but got the same result.

Answer (score -1):

@juanmac  My original post was deleted so I will answer here. Since you asked me a question there, I think it is fine I will answer inside your newest post ;)

A loop was used. Inside the loop, a `subscribeToMore` was used.
Inside that function, `updateQuery` was used.

There were some problems but I do not know if they were resolved. I will remind you, that it was React Native, and there are some stability issues with subscriptions etc.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi! thank's for the response.
Can you give me an example for that please? I've read hooks documentation and for loops aren't allowed https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: use the useQuery hook. It has `subscribeToMore`. Use that `subscribeToMore` in a loop. There is a `updateQuery` inside `subsToMore` function. Still, I have no idea if it actually worked correctly in the end. I hope that helps. I moved on from RN :)